# Cant find the referenced control on clicking menu item of ContextMenu in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, contextmenu, silverlight-toolkit

I have a collection of objects which i display in a databound listbox. The listbox contains the template which is defined as a StackPanel whcih contains a TextBlock. The TextBlock shows my data bounded from collection.

I am also associating the contextmenu using Silverlight toolkit for Windows Phone. I am associating ContextMenu and MenuItems programmatically to the selected TextBlock. I am handling every menu item by its own click event.

The problem that i face is that when i click the menuitem from contextmenu, i cannot get the referenced control from the listbox. In other words, I am not able to get the reference to TextBlock through which the contextmenu is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a method to get the element associated to a given ContextMenu, but as I can't find it, here's a workaround.

You say you are associating the ContextMenu with the TextBlock programatically. Then, you can use the wonderful [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) to hold a reference to your TextBlock. As you can read in the link, Tag holds any arbitrary object. The code would go like this:

First, you set the tag to your textblock (I'm using some generic names)

```
menuitem.Tag = textblock;
```

and then, in the click handler, retrieve that Textblock

```
var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
if(menuItem != null && menuItem.Tag is TextBlock)
   var textBlock = menuItem.Tag as TextBlock;
```

Then, textBlock is the TextBlock that called the ContextMenu.

Hope it helped.

Comment: There's no way in ContextMenu class to get the referenced comtrol. However for desktop wpf/silverlight, there is a PlacementTarget property that may help in getting the referenced control...<br />well thanx for the answer. I mark this once i try it. Bcoz its impotant to me. Thax anyways...:)